# json object over ajax gets CORRUPTED over POST request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I was testing this application,

Basically the browser sends a `json` which is an array of about 500 objects over POST,
When checking the recieved json by a php server with the help of debugger(xdebug),

There are many more elements in the array(about 2-4 times more) and many duplicates,it varies with request to request, No i've checked the same object with Net Panel in firefox web-dev tools, and the objects recieved by the server is different to that sent by the client(they do match occasionally) 
 My only guess is that the ajax is somehow being messed up over tcp? 
also the array indexes when checked by the debugger are like this,

```
[1]-->element
[2]-->element
[10]-->element    
[11]-->element
[12]-->element
```

So any clue what's going on here?

Comment: can you please put the code sending ajax request, the javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Check your post data limit (post_max_size for PHP) on the receiving server. 500 objects could be too big.

Comment: my post data limit is 8MB, and json data is about 88KB, I am recieving ALL the objects, however there are many dupicates of the same object throughout the array